# Length of a curve by integration: why won't flat segments do?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, intuition

Maybe my question is a duplicate, but I guess I don't know the right terminology to find it elsewhere. I would be happy to delete it if someone can point out a duplicate.

From elementary calculus, the length of a curve defined by a 'nice' function $f(x)$ between $x=a$ and $x=b$ is given by: 
$$s = \int\limits_{a}^{b} \left( 1+[f^\prime (x)]^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx$$

One derivation of this formula is to split the inverval $[a,b]$ into small segments of width $dx$, such that the length of $f(x)$ in each segment is given by $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2$, and then taking the limit as $dx \rightarrow 0$ of the sum of these lengths.

My question is: if we are eventually going to take the limit as $dx\rightarrow 0$, why won't it do just as well to approximate the length of $f(x)$ in a segment as being simply $dx$? (this would lead to the wrong expression).

I'm sure there must be a very rigorous reason for this in analysis, but I wonder if there might also be a more intuitive explanation?

(For some context, this question has been bugging me since high school, so by "intuitive" I guess I mean something that a high school student would be able to digest. Although now I might also be able to follow more formal explanations, if this could help in my understanding.)

Comment: You are basically setting $0$ for $dy$ as if it shouldn't matter. Why don't you just set $0$ for $dx$ as well, then you get always $0$...

Comment: Fair point. But here's another not-so-stupid case where this still fails: finding the surface area of a solid generated by a curve rotated around the x-axis. Approximate each segment as a cylinder, such that the contributed area is $2 \pi f(x) dx$ (now $f(x)$ is the radius of the cylinder, so it does come in. We still get the wrong answer, though.

Comment: The thing is.. you don't want to approximate by the absolute difference, which is of course small as you note. You want to approximate it so that the ratio of the areas is close to 1. Because when you sum many of these differences, you have no guarantee it won't get big (and it will in general), but the small ratio is preserved across the summation. That's the reason I think and the existence of derivatives provides you that.

Comment: You can do what you said but the resulting formula will be a poor approximation for arc length in general , except for the horizontal case y=c , in which case your formula gives the arc length exactly and the standard formula reduces to yours because y' = 0. :) 

Since most curves are not horizontal we need a way to parametrize the straight line distance between 2 very close points on a curve and the Pythagorean Theorem using the derivative of the curve is a nice way to do this parametrization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an excerpt of an earlier answer of mine:

[image]

The "area under the curve" $\gamma$ corresponding to a certain $\Delta x>0$ is roughly $f(\xi)\cdot \Delta x$, independently of the exact slope of the curve at $\xi$. Making $\Delta x$ smaller will decrease the relative area error committed here, since this error is only caused by the bending of the curve. But the length $\Delta s$ of the short arc corresponding to $\Delta x$ is roughly $={\Delta x\over\cos\phi}$, and making $\Delta x$ smaller does **not** make the factor ${1\over\cos\phi}$ go away. It follows that the final formula for the total length will have to incorporate the value ${1\over\cos\phi}=\sqrt{1+f'(\xi)^2}$.